# Angular 8 - ng build prod shows errors while ng serve works - Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module

Tags: angular, angular8, ng-build

My application builds and runs fine when using `ng serve` but shows errors when using `ng build --prod`. The error is in a dependency under `/node_modules/` so not sure how to fix this?

[image]

Error message:

`ERROR in Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'ExampleModule in /Users/Projects/KagiDocs/git/core/node_modules/@angular/material-examples/examples_public_index.d.ts'`

package.json

```
...
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^8.0.0",
  "@angular/cdk": "^8.1.4",
  "@angular/cdk-experimental": "^8.1.1",
  "@angular/common": "^8.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "^8.0.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^8.0.0",
  "@angular/material": "^8.1.4",
  "@angular/material-examples": "angular/material2-docs-content#8.1.x",
  "@angular/material-experimental": "^8.1.1",
  "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.1.4",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.0",
  "@angular/router": "^8.0.0",
  "core-js": "^2.6.1",
  "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
  "material-components-web": "^1.1.1",
  "moment": "^2.23.0",
  "rxjs": "^6.5.1",
  "zone.js": "^0.9.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.0",
  "@angular/cli": "^8.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.0.0",
  "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.5",
  "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
  "firebase-tools": "^6.2.2",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
  "karma": "^3.1.4",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
  "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
  "protractor": "~5.3.0",
  "ts-node": "^6.0.3",
  "tslint": "^5.10.0",
  "typescript": "3.4"
  } 
 }
```

We've . cloned this https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io codebase to build our project.

Comment: Do you need `@angular/material-examples` in the final build, or can you move it to dev dependencies only?

Comment: I don't know (following this repo as reference https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io). But i tried to move it and rebuilt using `ng build --prod` , same issue.

Comment: try removing the contents of your node_modules directory and then re-installing the modules with "npm install"

Comment: Tried it.. didn't help :(

Answer (score 1):

We are able to fix the issue, posting solution for reference:

Following the suggestions in https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/issues/629 , updating the version of `angular/material2-docs-content` in `package.json` to

```
"@angular/material-examples": "angular/material2-docs-content#8.0.x",
```

FIXED the issue.

There are issues when using:

```
"@angular/material-examples": "angular/material2-docs-content#8.1.x",
```